# Running ddev without database

Tags: database, docker, ddev

I want to set up a ddev (v1.5.2) project without a database. When I try to overwrite the image in a Docker-Compose YAML it stops with an error.

As suggested for the dba I have overwritten the db image in an additional `docker-compose.database.yaml` in the `.ddev` folder.

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: "busybox"
```

I expected it to start without the database and it does, but it seems to do a health check for the database which fails.

> Failed to start sitzplan: db container failed: log=, err=container exited, please use 'ddev logs -s db` to find out why it failed

The project is running, but it's not working, because it won't run my post-start hooks, which are necessary. In that means I can't even ignore the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that there's now explicit support for just turning off the dba/phpmyadmin container, `omit_containers: dba` (can also be done in the global ddev config, ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml).

And of course I would recommend just letting the regular db container run and not using it.

But here's a docker-compose.database.yaml that does what you ask for:

```html
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: "busybox:latest"
    command: sh -c "while true; do sleep 1000; done"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "true"]
```